# FFMPEG - batch extracting media duration and writing to a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I have ten media files in a folder. I want to create a text file containing two columns - filename and its duration (seconds):

```
video1.mp4|300 seconds 
video2.mp4|360 seconds 
video3.mp4|420 seconds 
... 
audio10.wav|120 seconds
```

I did not find any similar question on the Web, so I don't have any hint of how to do this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enumerate the media files and parse `Duration:` line in the output of `ffmpeg -i`:

```
@echo off
>output.txt (
    for %%F in (*.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav) do (
        for /f "tokens=2-5 delims=:., " %%a in (
            'ffmpeg -i "%%F" 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration:"'
        ) do (
            set /p =%%~nxF^|<nul
            setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
            set /a "duration=1%%a*3600 + 1%%b*60 + 1%%c - 366100"
            echo !duration!.%%d seconds
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
pause
```

With `ffprobe` (a part of ffmpeg package) the durations will have microsecond precision:

```
@echo off
>output.txt (
    for %%F in (*.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav) do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
            'ffprobe "%%F" -show_entries format^=duration -v quiet -of compact'
        ) do (
            echo %%~nxF^|%%a seconds
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Alternatively you can use a **much faster** [MediaInfo CLI](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows) to output duration in milliseconds:

```
>output.txt "C:\Program Files (x86)\MediaInfo\MediaInfoCLI.exe" ^
    --output=General;%%FileName%%.%%FileExtension%%^|%%Duration%%\r\n ^
    *.mpg *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi *.m4a *.flac *.mp3 *.wav
```

Comment: For me the duration field in the output of `ffmpeg` is formated as `hh:nn:ss.cc`, with two digits for each field. This code will fail if hours, minutes or seconds are `08` or `09`. Also delayed expansion will make it fail if the file name contains a `!`

Comment: It works. Usually it is easier to prefix the field with a `1` to  convert it to hundred to operate. If you change the order of the `for /f` options to include the space in the `delims` clause (dealing with the space in `%%a`) you can simplify it to `set /a "duration=1%%a*3600 + 1%%b*60 + 1%%c - 366100"`

Comment: @wOxxOm: thanks, but how to "enumerate the media files"? Where is the name and path to the output text file? Can you edit your answer for three media files ("1.mp4", "2.mp4" and "3.wav") and "data.txt" output file?

Comment: MC ND, thanks, that's very elegant. @lyrically wicked, see the updated code and don't forget that on stackoverflow you must invest some effort on your part :-)

Comment: @wOxxOm: "don't forget that on stackoverflow you must invest some effort on your part :-)" - this is not always possible :) Sorry, I am just not familiar with this scripting language. Can you explain what you meant by "enumerate the media files", please? What if I have many files in a folder, but only want to handle three files - "1.mp4", "2.mp4" and "3.wav"? How do I declare this?

Comment: @lyrically wicked, `*.something` is a [wildcard](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) that *enumerates* the files in the [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) loop, you can replace it with an actual file name.

Comment: @wOxxOm A better command for `ffmpeg` is: `ffprobe input.mp4 -show_entries format=filename,duration -v quiet`

Comment: @aergistal, yes, it simplifies the code a bit, thank you.

Comment: @wOxxOm: I tested that MediaInfo CLI code, and it writes a filename **with no extension** (that is, `"1"` instead of `"1.mp4"`). I fixed this by replacing `%%FileName%%` with `%%FileName%%^.%%FileExtension%%` – is this right?

Comment: @lyrically wicked, not exactly, see the fixed code.

Comment: Wasn't able to use the ffmped / ffprobe but MediaInfo_CLI worked perfectly. Listed the duration in miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

None of the scripts works.
"The system cannot find the path specified"

Paths:
D:\Videos\output\durations.txt
D:\Videos\various*.mp4
H:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg
H:\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33329293)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the below script to output in two formats.

If you omit this parameter {-sexagesimal} you will have the duration this way **sss.mmmmmm**

otherwise, but without writing the curly brackets, you'll have the classic **H:MM:SS.mmmmmm**

**Note:** *input-files* can be written star.star or *.mp4 or *mp4, *.mkv, *.mpg and so on.

```
@echo off
>"output-path\output_file.txt" (
for %%F in (input-path\input-files) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
        'ffprobe-path\ffprobe "%%F" -show_entries format^=duration {-sexagesimal} -v quiet -of compact'
    ) do (
        echo %%~nxF^|%%a
    )
)
```

)
pause