# How to set comma delimited values from stdout?

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I have a batch file that processes the output of an ffprobe query.  It retrieves several bits of data that I use to determine some ffmpeg directives.  In particular I'm converting h264 videos into h265 if the video frame height is 720 or greater.  I also convert the audio stream to aac if it isn't already and if that stream is higher than 128 kbps I convert it down to 128.

I can do all of that by calling ffprobe a number of times and use if statements to decide what my ffmpeg command will be.

I'd like my batch file to be more efficient so I was thinking that if I could take the output of one (maybe two) ffprobe queries and then stick that output into a for /f token=.... loop then I could set each ffprobe data point to a variable and then just check the variables to decide what the resulting ffmpeg command will be.

Here's what I have right now to simply check if the video stream is hevc.  If it isn't then ffmpeg converts the video to hevc and copies the audio to aac.

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do (
ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=index,codec_name,height -of csv "%%a" 2>&1 | findstr "hevc"
if errorlevel 1 (
    ffmpeg.exe -hwaccel cuvid -i "%%a" -pix_fmt p010le -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset slow -rc vbr_hq -b:v 4M -maxrate:v 10M -c:a aac "%%~na.h265-convert.mp4"
))
```

That ffprobe query output looks like this:

```
stream,0,h264,480
```

I was thinking if I could tokenize that output with something like:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims= " %%a in ("______") do set codec=%%b&set fheight=%%d
```

I don't know what to put in the spot where I have the _______.  I really don't want to create a temp file unless that's the only option though.

1) Is this an efficient way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

2) What do I use where I have a blank line above ________ to call the output of the ffprobe query to use in my for loop?

Comment: regarding 1), as you already recognized, batch is pain in the ass for string parsing plus ffprobe output is hard to parse. I'd recommend mediainfo as replacement like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344947/ffmpeg-batch-extracting-media-duration-and-writing-to-a-text-file

Comment: That's an idea.  I use the MediaInfo CLI for something else.  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims= " %%a in (
 'ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=index,codec_name,height -of csv "%%a" 2^>^&1 ^| findstr "hevc"'
) do set codec=%%b&set fheight=%%d
```

should execute the `ffprobe` command you've specified within the `for` statement.

It's possible that the `,` would also need to be escaped by a caret `^`.

The caret escapes the redirector characters so that they are accepted as part of the command to be executed, not the `for` itself.

To execute a command, enclose it in `'single quotes'`

Given the output you suggest, I can see no way in which it would get through the `findstr` filter for `hevc` since it does not contain `hevc`. Also, the output yo mention is comma-separated, so the `delims` option should be <kbd>,</kbd> not <kbd>Space</kbd>

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation - and thousands of examples here on SO.

Comment: I'll need to play around with that for a bit, but it looks like it should work.  The findstr bit is from what I'm doing now where ffmpeg processes if hevc ISN'T found.  I won't need to use findstr with this way if it works.

Comment: the `/v` switch on `findstr` reverses the sense and reports lines where the target string was *not* found.

Comment: Here's what I've got but for some reason the variables aren't being set.  When I run the following all I get is "dog" for the output which is what I should get if the variables are not set/empty:

`for %%a in ("*.*") do (
 for /f "tokens=* delims=," %%a in ('ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=index^,codec_name^,height -of csv "%%a" 2^>^&1') do set codec=%%c&set fheight=%%d

 if /I "%codec%" == "" (
  echo dog
 ) else (
  echo goldfish
 )
)`

Comment: You need to find out about `delayedexpansion` - there are hundreds of articles about it on SO. Essentially, any `%var%` within a `for` loop will be *replaced* by its value *at the time the loop is checked for validity* that is, the very first time the `for` is encountered. Consequently, the variable *appears* to be unchanged. I'd suggest you also view the help on the `CALL` instruction (`call /?` from the prompt) and execute your `if` within a subroutine.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Everything is working as intended now.  I also figured out another issue which is that when I had tokens=* nothing worked properly.  I kept getting ECHO is off every time I tried to echo a variable.  After adding the changes you suggested and changing tokens to 1,2,3,4 everything worked like a charm.  I'm not a programmer.  I just find things that work better in my hobbies and (usually) figure out a way to get them to work faster with scripts.  I had never heard of delayed expansion until now so than you for letting me know about it.