# Sort videos by bytes/second

Tags: windows, batch-file, video

I'm trying to find a way to sort videos by their bytes/second (b/s) ratio. I don't mean the b/s rates which one can set when rendering videos, but the actual "how big is this file" divided by "how long is the video" ratio.

The videos are in different folders (all contained in one parent folder) and I don't want to change their location with the sorting. I want a descending list with the filename, optionally the path to that file and the ratio of b/s; commandline-output would be fine.

Is there any way to do this in Windows natively? I assume there isn't, so my question is rather: How would one do that? My best guess is to try to write a .bat script for that but there might also be programs for something like that already.

Comment: Well chrismas is near, you know whom to present a wish list ... [SO] isn't a script writing service. Own research and code attempts ere expected.

Comment: Flagged as should be closed because it asks just for a software recommendation

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this seems quite easy to do by getting the bitrate of the files via ffmpeg

[FFMPEG - batch extracting media duration and writing to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344947/ffmpeg-batch-extracting-media-duration-and-writing-to-a-text-file)

Comment: So? And the other requirements? Process videos in different folders and output the descending list with optional paths? This two-lines reply would be a good comment, but certainly not an answer...

Comment: Well for that just some more .bat stuff has to be added. I agree that my question was kind of too broad in the first place, but at least someone who's asking himself the same can now see that it can easily be solved with batch.